# What's wrong with this user ignore file for Mercurial?

Tags: regex, mercurial, hgignore

A little retrospective now that I've settled into Mercurial. Forget forget files combined with `hg remove`. It's crazy and bass-ackwards. You can use `hg remove` once you've established that something is in a forget file that isn't forgetting because the item in question was tracked before the original repo was created. Note that `hg remove` effectively clears tracked status but it also schedules the file for deletion in anything that gets changes from your repo. If ignored, however the tracking deactivation still happens but that delete-me change set won't ever reach another repo and for some reason will never delete in yours which IMO is counter-intuitive. It is a very sure sign that somebody and I don't know these guys, is UNWILLING TO COMPROMISE ON DUH DESIGN PROBLEMS. The important thing to understand is that you don't determine what's important, Mercurial does. Except when you're merging on a pull of course. It's entirely reasonable then. But I digress...

Ignore-file/remove is a good combo for already-tracked but very specific files you want forgotten but if you're dealing with a larger quantity of built files determined with broader patterns it's not worth the risk. Just go with a double-repo and `pull -u` from the remote repo to your syncing repo and then `pull -u` commits from your working repo and merge in a repo whose sole purpose is to merge changes and pass them on in a place where your not-quite tracked or untracked files (behavior is different when pulling rather than pushing of course because hey, why be consistent?) won't cause frustration. Trust me. The idea that you should have to have two repos just to get 'er done offends for good reason AND THAT SO MANY OF US ARE DOING IT should suggest a serioush !@#$ing design problem, but it's much less painful than all the other awful things that will make you regret seeking a sensible alternative.

And use `hg help`. It's actually Mercurial's best feature and often better than the internet (which I don't fault for confusion on the matter of all things hg) for getting answers to everything that is confusing and counter-intuitive in this VCS.

**/retrospective**

```
# switch to regexp syntax.
syntax: regexp


#Config Files

#.Net
^somecompany\.Net[\\/]MasterSolution[\\/]SomeSolution[\\/]SomeApp[\\/]app\.config
^somecompany\.Net[\\/]MasterSolution[\\/]SomeSolution[\\/]SomeApp_test[\\/]App\.config

#and more of the same following
```

And in my mercurial.ini at the root of my user directory

```
[ui]
username = ereppen
merge = bcomp
ignore = C:\<path to user ignore file>\.hgignore-config
```

Context:

I wrote an auto-config utility in node. I just want changes to the files it changes to get ignored. We have two teams and both aren't on the same page with making this a universal thing so it needs to be user-specific for now.

The config file is in place and pointed at by my ini file. I clone. I run the config utility and change the files and stat reveals a list of every single file with an M next to it. I thought it was the utf-8 thing and explicitly set the file to utf-16 little endian. I don't think I'm doing with the regEx that any modern flavor of regEx worth actually calling regEx wouldn't support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.hgignore` file has no effect for files that are tracked.  Its function is to stop you from seeing files you want ignored listed as "untracked".  If you're seeing "M" then they're already added (you got them with the clone) so `.hgignore` does nothing.

The usual way config files that differ from machine to machine are handled is to put a `app.config.sample` in source control, have `app.config` in `.hgignore` and have people do a copy when they're making their config edits.

Alternately if your config files allow for includes and overrides you end them with `include app-local.config` and override any settings in a `app-local.config` which you don't add and do include in `.hgignore`.

Comment: So there's no way to have something local that establishes what doesn't need to be tracked from a clone?

Comment: That is correct.  You can pass "everything else" as an argument to `hg commit` and you can use `--exclude thing/to/exclude` with some commands, and can even create aliases (shell or in-mercurial) so that `hg mycommit` does a commit with those excludes, but there's no config file way to say "I made changes to a file I've told you is important, but I don't care".  The `whatever.sample` this is what most any project you'll find does.

Comment: Cool. Puzzled as to why Mercurial wants you to add all these steps for doing simple things like this but thanks for the help.

Comment: @ErikReppen it wasn't my decision but it's probably a sound one.  Not tracking a change can be disasterous and the `.hgignore` file is tracked, so you'll get my changes when you pull+update. So if ignore could ignore tracked files and I put `src/submodule` in there you'll be not-commiting and not-pushing changes in submodule w/o any warning .  Adding a file, making it tracked is saying "this is *important*" and having something that's both important and to which edits are ignored goes against that.  Some folks use 'mq' to keep local overlays for tracked files, but I prefer the .sample anyway.

Comment: Okay, but I should be able to say "all but these are important." That seems like kind of an obvious thing to want to do. I'm not tracking file by file. I'm tracking directories full of files and other directories. The minority is the files I don't want to track but there's still enough of those that it's a PITA to list each one individually more than once. When I do a clone, it can read my ini file and it can read the ignore list I'm pointing at from there. I honestly don't even understand the point of the user-specific ignore list as-is.

Comment: @ErikReppen you can absolutely ignore files and say "all but these are important"  That's what `.hgignore` does, but `.hgignore` *can't* override `adding`.  Indeed, some folks put `.*` (everything) in their hgignore and then `hg add` the specific files about which they care.  `.hgignore` is to prevent you from accidentally adding things, nothing more.  A good usecase for per-user .hgignores are editor swap files.  The repo's `.hgignore` doesn't need to have my editor's swap file pattern in it, but I don't want to ever add them in any repo.